# Can I loop componentWillMount until I get the user_key from API?

Tags: react-native, async-await, react-navigation

I am trying to use react navigation authentication flow to manage the login screen if the user is logged in or not. But now I got stuck in AsyncStorage. So while the user is not logged in I presume that componentWillMount will wait until the user will input the credentials, tap the login button, receive the user_id from API call and then try again. For me now it is calling what in the beginning which is fine but then I have to exit from app and go back to get the dashboard rendered. Any solution?

This is my code from App.js where I'm creating the routes as well. Also I am loading redux map on bottom.

```
export const createRootNavigator = (signedIn = false) => {
  return SwitchNavigator(
    {
      SignedIn: {
        screen: SignedIn
      },
      SignedOut: {
        screen: SignedOut
      }
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: signedIn ? "SignedIn" : "SignedOut"
    }
  );
};

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      signedIn: false,
      checkedSignIn: false
    };
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    await isSignedIn()
        .then(res => this.setState({ signedIn: res, checkedSignIn: true }))
        .catch(err => alert("An error occurred"));
  }

  render() {
    const { checkedSignIn, signedIn } = this.state;

    // If we haven't checked AsyncStorage yet, don't render anything (better ways to do this)
    if (!checkedSignIn) {
      return null;
    }

    const Layout = createRootNavigator(signedIn);
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ffffff'}}>
          <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"/>
          <Layout />
          <AlertContainer/>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
};
```

And here is the Auth.js where I am waiting for the user_key.

```
export let USER_KEY = 'myKey';

export const onSignIn = async () => { await AsyncStorage.setItem(USER_KEY, 'true') };
export const onSignOut = async () => { await AsyncStorage.removeItem(USER_KEY) };

export const isSignedIn = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(USER_KEY)
      .then(res => {
        if (res !== null) {
          // console.log('true')
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          resolve(false);
          // console.log('false')
        }
      })
      .catch(err => reject(err));
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to make use of Splashscreen. You can add a splashscreen to the App. While Splashscreen is being displayed, check if user exists in Asyncstorage, if they do, navigate user to the Dashboard/Homescreen and if asynstorage responds null, navigate user to the Login page. Once Navigation is complete, you can hide the splashscreen. Checkout this package in npmjs for Splashscreen setup `react-native-splash-screen`